# Trouble understanding how to use jquery Deferred/then with callbacks

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, deferred

My current javascript code looks essentially like::

```
function doStep1(callback) {
  thirdPartyLib.asyncExec('step1', {}, function(resp) { 
     callback(resp.value); 
   });
}
function doStep2(value, callback) {
  thirdPartyLib.asyncExec('step2', value, function(resp) { 
     callback(resp.value); 
   }); 
}
function doStep3(value, callback) {
  thirdPartyLib.asyncExec('step3', value, function(resp) { 
     callback(resp.value); 
   }); 
}
function displayResult(value) {
  $('#input').enable();
  $('#result').text(value);
}

function run() {
   doStep1(function(x){doStep2(x,function(y){doStep3(y,displayResult)}});
}
```

I.e., we need to call three separate asynchronous functions whereby the result of each function is passed to the next.  But the syntax is pretty horrible, even in this grossly simplified version. I'm hoping I can use something like jquery's deferred/promises support to write something that would like more like:

```
$.when(doStep1).then(doStep2).then(doStep3).then(displayResult);
```

But clearly this isn't the right syntax, and I'm not sure I really understand what syntax I should be using to achieve this, as everything I've tried ends up looking more complicated than my run() function above, which defeats the purpose. 
For kicks, I actually wrote my own version of 'when' and 'then' that would allow the above syntax (you still have to call, e.g. 'resolve' or something at the end to actually make the call, mind you), so I know it should be possible, but maybe the jQuery library just isn't designed for this scenario?

Comment: similar question is answered here using "async" and "q": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750280/how-to-handle-an-async-function-that-depends-on-multiple-other-async-functions

Comment: As small class/plugin: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hv50Lcfh/4/).

Comment: And with passing value: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hv50Lcfh/5/).

Comment: Impressive, that actually does work pretty nicely...but it does mean having to write the callback functions with a very particular signature, and I'm wondering how it will look with error handling put in too. Big thank you though, even if I don't feel I quite have my head around it yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to write this. Exactly what you write depends on the nature of the unsimplified code.

Let's make an assumption :

> All third-party calls are of similar enough form that a generalised
>   `doStep()` function can be written, which can be commanded to perform
>   any step.

Taking the simplified code at face value, then this assumption is met and the code is reasonably trivial :

```
function doStep(step, value) {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
        thirdPartyLib.asyncExec(step, value, dfrd.resolve);
    }).then(function(resp) {
        return resp.value;
    });
}
function displayResult(value) {
    $('#input').enable();
    $('#result').text(value);
}
function run(steps) {
    return steps.reduce(function(promise, step) {
        return promise.then(function(value) {
            return doStep(step, value);
        });        
    }, $.when( {} ));// the empty object here becomes the `value` passed anongside 'step1'.
}

//The asychronous sequence is determined by an array passed to run()
run(['step1', 'step2', 'step3']);
```

If each third-party call is of a different form, then the code will be more complicated but probably still not too bad.

Comment: It looks neat, but I can't really see how it will work in the realistic case that the parameter passing and results parsing for each 3rd party library call is actually quite different. But it definitely helps me understand a little better how to pass values from one function to the next, so thanks.

Comment: The code above is about as concise as I can get it. If the 3rd party library calls differ greatly then the overall structure can be detuned while keeping the central theme of the "supervisor" `run()`. Your first resort is to branch with eg a switch/code structure in `doStep()`. If that's not enough, you can go back to separate "doStepX" functions and arrange for `run()` to call the appropriate function at each step.

Comment: The last resort is to pass an array of *functions* with parameters bound-in using `fn.bind()`, to a modified `run()`.

Comment: And I should have said, `Array.prototype.reduce` is fast becoming the *de facto* solution to building a `.then()` chain from an array of data. People who programme async stuff are becoming familiar with this in ever increasing numbers. BTW, I didn't invent it, I ain't that clever.